# how to set range of x-axis with timestamp for xylinechart in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, timestamp, linechart

How to set range of x-axis with Time stamp for `xylinechart` in javaFX ?

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at javafx.scene.chart.ValueAxis.invalidateRange(ValueAxis.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.updateAxisRange(LineChart.java:174)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(XYChart.java:668)
```

Comment: The error states it clearly, you have trying to cast `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.lang.Number`. If you can add some code, it would help us to point out the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that ValueAxis extends Axis<Number>. I'm guessing you're trying to add Timestamp values to the dataseries on that range. Try this (Timestamp is a subclass of Date):

http://myjavafx.blogspot.com/2013/09/javafx-charts-display-date-values-on.html